# jquery not running when linked to an external js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever I put the script in another file in the same folder as script.js, it doesn't run. It only runs when I include my code in the script tag.

I tried it out with this simple jquery code. Whenever the third script tag is uncommented, it works, but the set up I have right now doesn't run.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="script.js"></script> // <!-- doesn't run -->
    <!--script> // <!-- only runs inside the html file -->
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('p').click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script-->
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click to hide.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scr` is not `src`. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org) to make sure you haven't misspelt attribute names.

Comment: Right.  Any time you write or revise HTML, do this: http://validator.w3.org/ It will save you hours of time.

Answer (score -1):

Your jQuery code is being duplicated inside the **script.js** file and **.html** file so that's why the code won't run.

Remove the jQuery code from the **.html** file and your code will run. Also like was mention above replace **scr** with **src** in your **.html** file.

Finally, I'd replace the code in your **script.js** file with the new code listed below as *click(function(){}* is older code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").on("click", function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```